# Hyperledger Composer v0.19 Hiding Historian in ACL

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I would like to ask how to hide the Historian // Transaction log in v0.19?

I have tried this from an example -->

```
    rule hideHistorianAccess{
    description: "Deny access to Historian"
    participant: "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
    action: DENY
    }

    rule historianAccess{
    description: "Only allow members to read historian records referencing transactions they submitted."
    participant(p): "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
    operation: READ
    resource(r): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
    condition: (r.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
    }
```

But none of this seems to work, I would like to hide adding new participants mostly, but if that is not possible I would like to hide the complete transaction log. I have personal details in the participant fields which I would not like to make publicly accessible.

Comment: Did you post your complete ACL file ? If that was the only contents of your ACL file then pretty much nothing will work as the default is to deny unless explicitly allowed and the only thing you are allowing is to look at HistorianRecord entries. For example there is nothing to allow anyone to look at the list of historian records (you need to be able to access the HistorianRecord asset registry otherwise you cannot get any of the HistorianRecord entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by david_k - the context of your rules (above) in relation to ALL rules in permissions.acl would be needed to understand why you saw what you did.

It appears from a Rocketchat conversation that the issue was related to the ORDER of the rules in the ruleset,  ie a more 'general' rule is evaluated ahead of the 'specific' rule in the lexical rules evaluation, and found a match (so subsequent 'specific' rule wasn't evaluated, hence why you saw those results initially).

An example of that is shown below:

*'CORRECT ORDER'*

```
// specifically allow users to see historian records they invoked
rule historianAccess{
  description: "Only allow members to read historian records referencing transactions they submitted."
  participant(p): "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
  operation: READ
  resource(r): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  condition: (r.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}

// prevent users from seeing historian records
rule hidehistorianAccess{
  description: "Deny access to Historian"
  participant: "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
  operation: READ
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  action: DENY
}
```

vs *'INCORRECT ORDER'*:

```
rule hidehistorianAccess{
  description: "Deny access to Historian"
  participant: "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
  operation: READ
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  action: DENY
}

rule historianAccess{
  description: "Only allow members to read historian records referencing transactions they submitted."
  participant(p): "org.blockknowhow.com.Users"
  operation: READ
  resource(r): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  condition: (r.participantInvoking.getIdentifier() == p.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW

}
```

Comment: jverhoelen is right btw - 'DENY' is the default (implicit) so you only need one rule; I only answered in the generic context of 2 rules provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first rule is not needed. With your `ALLOW` rule for only particular participants under a strict condition, every other participant not matching the condition will get its actions *denied*.

I see that you found the `ALLOW` rule [in the docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-website/jekylldocs/business-network/historian.md#securing-historian-data) and this also looks good, I wouldn't approach it differently. But to get it running, try deleting the first rule. If that's not working out, I would recommend creating an issue at `composer` on Github.